# routing error, no route match for rails api request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, request, initialization, constants

I've got my controller namespaced with `API`, and can't seem to make a request due to the following error:
`ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/api/request_projects")`

Controller:

```
module Api
  class Api::ProjectsController < ApplicationController  
    def request_projects
      items = []
      page = 1
      total_count = Project.request_total_count
      pages = Project.get_page_count(total_count)
      pages.times do
        items << Project.request_projects(page)
        items_list = items.flatten
        Project.create_from_request(items_list) if !items_list.empty?
        page += 1
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  root 'pages#index'

  namespace :api, defaults: { format: 'json' } do
    resources :projects
  end

  match '*path', to: 'projects#request_projects', via: :all
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You're declaring `Api::Api::ProjectsController`.

```
module Api
  class ProjectsController < ApplicationController  
    def request_projects
      items = []
      page = 1
      total_count = Project.request_total_count
      pages = Project.get_page_count(total_count)
      pages.times do
        items << Project.request_projects(page)
        items_list = items.flatten
        Project.create_from_request(items_list) if !items_list.empty?
        page += 1
      end
    end
  end
end
```

> Define (and reopen) namespaced classes and modules using explicit
>   nesting. Using the scope resolution operator can lead to surprising
>   constant lookups due to Ruby’s lexical scoping, which depends on the
>   module nesting at the point of definition.
>   - https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide

As to the routing issue - you have a catch-all defined that should match `/api/request_projects`. As `*path` will match everything. I have no idea why you would want to do this though. Just declare the actual route you want to use instead. Catch-alls are a last resort that come with a huge amount of potential bugs.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  root 'pages#index'

  namespace :api, defaults: { format: 'json' } do
    resources :projects
    resources :request_projects
  end
end
```